# Have two charts in charts.js one below the other with some co-relation between them

Tags: chart.js

[Highcharts master-detail chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0guRq.png)
I am looking to have this kind of functionality added in my application. While highcharts has this capability, I was wondering if we can do something similar using charts.js too.
Use case: Plot a line chart at first from data received from API. Now to further drill down to see what all incidents occurred during particular time frame displayed on x-axis of chart, I want to plot another chart just below the existing chart.

So far, from chart.js examples I could only see, multiple axis supported but not an example where we can plot new data on those multiple axes.
[multi x-axes example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icLej.png)
In above example, I could add a new scale below existing one, but to plot data to that scale, that point I am missing.

code used:

```
const options = {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "# of Votes",
        data: [
          {
            x: new Date("09-08-2021 12:04"),
            y: 10,
          },
          {
            x: new Date("09-08-2021 12:08"),
            y: 15,
          },
          {
            x: new Date("09-08-2021 12:12"),
            y: 5,
          },
          {
            x: new Date("09-08-2021 12:30"),
            y: 8,
          },
        ],
        borderColor: "pink",
        yAxisID: "y",
      },
      {
        type: "bar",
        label: "# of Points",
        data: [
          {
            x: new Date("09-08-2021 12:04"),
            y: 4,
            x2: 5
          },
          {
            x: new Date("09-08-2021 12:08"),
            y: 6,
            x2: 5
          },
          {
            x: new Date("09-08-2021 12:12"),
            y: 12,
            x2: 5
          },
          {
            x: new Date("09-08-2021 12:30"),
            y: 18,
            x2: 5
          },
          {
            x: new Date("09-08-2021 12:022"),
            y: 10,
            x2: 5
          },
          {
            x: new Date("09-08-2021 12:38"),
            y: 15,
            x2: 5
          },
          {
            x: new Date("09-08-2021 12:52"),
            y: 5,
            x2: 5
          },
          {
            x: new Date("09-08-2021 12:59"),
            y: 8,
            x2: 5
          },
        ],
        backgroundColor: "orange",
        xAxisID: "x2",
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: "time",
      },
      y: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: "Car Speed, mph",
          font: {
            size: 24,
          },
        },
      },
      x2: {
        position: "bottom",
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: "second X",
          font: {
            size: 24,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

  new Chart(document.getElementById("acquisitions"), options);
```